# Hydrolysis of Magnesium Carbide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrolysis

I came across a question in which the following reaction was taking place:

$$
\ce{Mg4C3 + H2O -> CH3CH \bond{#} CH}
$$

Each $\ce{Mg}$ atom must be present in a +2 oxidation state, thus the total charge of the cation is +8. We thus have a $\ce{C3^{8-}}$ anion. The only structure of this $\ce{C3^{8-}}$ anion I could come up with was three carbons attached to each other in a linear fashion, with the terminal carbons each bearing a -3 charge and the central carbon bearing a -2 charge.

From this anion I would have assumed that the product formed upon hydrolysis is propane, but the product formed in the above reaction is propyne, just like when $\ce{Mg2C3}$ undergoes hydrolysis.

I'm guessing that the explanation for propyne being formed is the actual lattice structure of $\ce{Mg4C3}$, but I couldn't find any literature referencing this reaction or the structure of $\ce{Mg4C3}$.

The question is taken from:

- V.K. Jaiswal, s-block elements, Problems in Inorganic Chemistry, Thirteenth Edition, Page 331, question 36

Comment: @Poutnik agreed, but if the 3 carbon atoms don't form a single anion, how will we get a product which consists of 3 interconnected carbon atoms?

Comment: The polyatomic ion C4−
3, sometimes called allylide, is found in Li4C3 and Mg2C3. The ion is linear and is isoelectronic with CO2. The C-C distance in Mg2C3 is 133.2 pm. Mg2C3 yields methylacetylene, CH3CCH, and propadiene, CH2CCH2, on hydrolysis, which was the first indication that it contains C4−
3.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbide

Comment: @Poutnik so are you claiming that $\ce{Mg4C3}$ consists of the $\ce{C3^{4-}}$ anion? Then how is the charge balanced, since Mg is in a +2 oxidation state, and thus the cation has a total charge of +8?

Comment: I have just quoted Wikipedia, I have not claimed anything. Note Mg2C3, not Mg4C3.

Comment: Typo? Should it be Mg2C3?

Comment: Yeah, seems a blatant mistake.

Comment: I don’t know if this is enough to prove that this is not a typo but [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/265143556.pdf) paper mentions Mg4C3

Comment: Probably they mistyped Mg2C3.  Lithium, with its diagonal relationship, does form a Li4C3 carbide with hydrolysis characteristics similar to Mg2C3.

Comment: Assuming the reagent is Mg2C3, one way to visualize the reaction can be as follows: Purely on oxidation state basis, each Mg will be charged +2, with 2 Mg atoms you get +4 positive charge. That means the anionic end has three carbon atoms required to bear a combined oxidation state of -4. Check it yourself that one possible way to have that is to make a cyclopropene-like moiety (C3H4). The two doubly-bonded carbons can bear a -1 charge, while the apex carbon can bear a -2 charge.

Comment: This cyclopropene-like moiety is extremely unstable due to the unbelievably high ring strain. Hence, in the presence of water, the ring will quickly open-up and hydrolyse by picking up protons from the water. This will straight-away give you propyne.